# How not to stop the execution of other function in python in case of Exception/Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, decorator

I have a script in python which works as shown below. Each function performs a completely different task and not related to each other. My problem is if **function2()** is having an issue during the execution process then **function3()**, **function4()**, **function5()** will not execute. I know you will say to handle this by catching the exception (try..except) but then i have to catch every exception which is not i am looking for. In a nutshell how do i code where my other functions are not impacted if any of the function is having issue. Ideally it should exclude that problematic function and let the other function to execute.

```
def function1():
    some code

def function2():
    some code

def function3():
    some code

def function4():
    some code

def function5():
    some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
    function4()
    function5()
```

Comment: Two thoughts: You don`t have to catch every single exception by just not naming the concrete exception, right? I guess this should work... Or you just execute function2() at the end of function1(), so if there is an error before, it will not go as far and break earlier.

Comment: if exception handling is an issue due to code lenght, you could write a function that "wraps" all your functions in a `try - except` block like `def wrap_em(func_list): for func in func_list: try: func except: continue`

Comment: @nostradamus - The thing is I tried what you just mentioned. Basically my function contains several web crawlers. So i am not sure when my function can break. So piling them up according to which function will have an issue will not work in this case.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - This can be a solution but lets see what other have to say.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to write multiple `try/except`. Create a list of your function and execute them. For example, you code should be like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_list = [function1, function2, function3, function4, function5]

    for my_func in func_list:
        try:
            my_func()
        except:
            pass
```

---

OR, create a *decorator* and add that decorator to each of your function. Check [A guide to Python's function decorators](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/). For example, your decorator should be like:

```
def wrap_error(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
           return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
           pass
    return func_wrapper
```

Now add this decorator with your function definition as:

```
@wrap_error
def function1():
    some code
```

Functions having this decorator added to them won't raise any `Exception`

Comment: the only problem i see with that are arguments. you cannot pass arguments to the functions you are running like that.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You can. In that case you need to make it as `dict` instead of list.  `Key` will be function and `value` will be arguments. Data structure depends on the requirement :)

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 3.4, a new context manager as [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) is added which as per the doc:

> Return a context manager that suppresses any of the specified exceptions if they occur in the body of a `with` statement and then resumes execution with the first statement following the end of the with statement.

In order to suppress all the exceptions, you may use it as:

```
from contextlib import suppress

if __name__ == '__main__':

    func_list = [function1, function2, function3, function4, function5]

    for my_func in func_list:
        with suppress(Exception):  # `Exception` to suppress all the exceptions
            my_func()  # Any exception raised by `my_func()` will be suppressed
```

Comment: This won't actually do what OP wanted. If function1 raises an exception, function2 will not be executed.

Comment: @Decko Sorry for the late response. Updated the answer to fix it. I missed that part earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can use exception and catch all sort of exceptions like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        function1()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        function2()
    except:
        pass    
    try:
        function3()
    except:
        pass    
    try:
        function4()
    except:
        pass
```

for large number of functions you can use

```
func_dict = {
 func1 : {
     param1 : val
     param2 : val
   },
 func1 : {
     param1 : val
     param2 : val
   }
}
```

thus you can iterate over the keys of the dictionary for the function and iterate on the parameters

Comment: as far as i understood it, this is what OP explicitly said he does not want to have.

Comment: what I understood that , he was planning to write down every exception that might come up explicitly. But rather he can catch all the exception

Comment: This way is out of the picture because my functions contains around 15 web crawlers and coding in this way is not pythonic.